# My loop works like this: loop, script, loop. I want this: loop, loop, code. The ForgottenServer 0.3.6

Tags: loops, for-loop, lua

this is the code with loop:

```
            for _, pid in ipairs(getPlayersOnline()) do 
                if getCreatureStorage(pid, tmp[i].storeDamage) > -1 then 
                    doPlayerSendTextMessage(cid, MESSAGE_STATUS_CONSOLE_ORANGE, getPlayerName(pid)..': '..getCreatureStorage(pid, 11005))
                end
                doCreatureSetStorage(pid, tmp[i].storeDamage, -1) 
            end
```

every players with a storage 11005 get the message like:

Player name:random number
The current player is CID and every online players are PID.
Now I want to set the random number to -1 after the message is shown to every online players.
The problem is that the loop works like this:
show the message to CID (first player) then reset number to -1 and then show the message to second player. It cannot be done that way, because first player sees correct message like:

> player name1:number of player1, player name2:numberof player2

but second player sees

> player name1:-1(number of this player), player name2:-1 (nr of second player).

Loop has been done this way probably: loop, setStorage, loop.
I need this way: loop, loop, set storage.
I've tried to check the last loop using "

> if next(getPlayersOnline(), _) == nil then

, but does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you just move the "set storage" to a second loop after the first? That's the only way that you'll be able to send all of the messages before doing any of the set storage calls.

```
for _, pid in ipairs(getPlayersOnline()) do 
  if getCreatureStorage(pid, tmp[i].storeDamage) > -1 then 
    doPlayerSendTextMessage(cid, MESSAGE_STATUS_CONSOLE_ORANGE, getPlayerName(pid)..': '..getCreatureStorage(pid, 11005))
  end
end
for _, pid in ipairs(getPlayersOnline()) do 
  doCreatureSetStorage(pid, tmp[i].storeDamage, -1) 
end
```